# working with expressions: how to minimize runtime construction time

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

I have two classes, a single expression (`SE`) and a bundle of two expressions (`ME`). The bundle is an expression itself, hence it can be an element of another bundle.

```
struct SE {
    SE(char id, char n) : id(id), n(n) {}

    size_t size() const { return n; }
    char *eval(char *b) const { b[0]=id; return b+1; }

    char id, n;
};

template <typename LHS>
struct ME {
    ME(const LHS& l, const SE& r) : lhs(l), rhs(r) { }

    size_t size() const { return rhs.size(); }
    char *eval(char *b) const { *b++='('; b=lhs.eval(b); *b++=','; b=rhs.eval(b); *b++=')'; return b; }

    LHS lhs;
    SE rhs;
};
```

The construction of the bundle performs a simple validity check based on the data member `n`, accessible in `ME` via the method `size`. An `eval` method does some claculations using the data member `id`. Neither `n` nor `id` are known at compile time.

For both classes I override the comma operator, so that it performs the recursive bundling of multiple single expression into a nested bundle.

```
auto SE::operator,(const SE& r) { return ME<SE>(*this, r); }
auto ME<LHS>::operator,(const SE& r) { return ME<ME<LHS>>(*this, r); }
```

I want that, after the whole bundle has been constructed, the method `eval` is triggered on the whole bundle. Example:

```
SE('a',1);                        // prints 'a'
SE('a',1), SE('b',1);             // prints '(a,b)'
SE('a',1), SE('b',1), SE('c',1);  // prints '((a,b),c)'
```

A possible way to achieve that is to use the destructors of the classes and add a flag `is_outer` which is updated appropriately during contruction of `SE` and `ME`. When any of these class is destructed, if the flag indicates this is the *outermost* class, then `eval` is triggered. A full demo is given below.

Testing on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/2NSFNA) the simple `demo` function below, it seems to me the compiler generates more code than strictly necessary. Although `id` and `n` are not known at compile time, the final type of the expression should be. I would expect the entire construction of the bundle to reduce to just moving a few numbers in the correct place, then check the assertions, but it seems to actually do much more copies.

Is it possible to obtain that more of the contruction part is produced at compile time?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

// forward declaration
template <typename LHS> struct ME;

struct SE {
    SE(char id, char n) : id(id), n(n), outer(true)  {}
    SE(const SE& expr) : id(expr.id), n(expr.n), outer(false) {}

    ME<SE> operator,(const SE& r);

    size_t size() const { return n; }
    char *eval(char *b) const { b[0]=id; return b+1; }

    ~SE() { if(outer) { char b[20] = {}; char *p=eval(b); *p++='\n'; cout << b; } }

    char id, n;
    mutable bool outer;
};

template <typename LHS>
struct ME {
    ME(const LHS& l, const SE& r)
        : lhs(l), rhs(r), outer(true)  // tentatively set to true
    { l.outer = r.outer = false;  assert(l.size() == r.size()); } // reset flag for arguments
    ME(const ME<LHS>& expr)
        : lhs(expr.lhs), rhs(expr.rhs), outer(false) {}

    size_t size() const { return rhs.size(); }
    char *eval(char *b) const { *b++='('; b=lhs.eval(b); *b++=','; b=rhs.eval(b); *b++=')'; return b; }

    auto operator,(const SE& r) { return ME<ME<LHS>>(*this, r); }

    ~ME() { if(outer) { char b[20] = {}; char *p=eval(b); *p++='\n'; cout << b; } }

    LHS lhs;
    SE rhs;
    mutable bool outer;
};

ME<SE> SE::operator,(const SE& r) { return ME<SE>(*this, r); }

void demo(char a, char na, char b, char nb, char c, char nc) {
    SE(a, na), SE(b,nb), SE(c,nc);   // prints '((a,b),c)'
}

int main() {
    demo('a',1,'b',1,'c',1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For working code, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ seems more appropriate.

Comment: "How to determine if the class is the outermost or not?": you cannot, but you can determine if a class is _not_ the outermost (the constr of `ME` can alert (inhibit) those `AssignExpr` they are not the outermost). Your solution is then to trigger evaluation if a class has not received an inhibiting signal.

Comment: And this is what you do. See Jarod's comment then ;)

Answer (score 1):

The general pattern you are following is expression templates.  Reading up on how others do it will help.

Usually expression templates use CRTP heavily, and do not store copies.

I believe I see bugs due to the copies.

Generally take `T&&` and store `T&` or `T&&`.

Usually expression templates terminate (and execute) when they are assigned to a target; you don't want to that.  As C++ lacks move-from-and-destroy, you have to check the "should not be executed" at (nominally) runtime.

Instead of references/values and a bool, you could store pointers and use null as the "don't run" case.

I cannot figure out how to make the work to determine what to run `constexpr`.  It might be possible however.

Comment: Hi. I simplified a lot the question and the source code. Indeed my final objective is to achieve that the runtime construction of the final expression is as fast as it could be. It seems to me that your answer touches the right topics, but it is too high level for me to make good use of it. Would you mind elaborating? Thank you.